# Nodejs Angularjs Mongoose Query inside async map

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

From the codes below, I can add to my database. However, when I am trying to mongoose-find to look for the database, I am not getting any value. can anybody help? I want to res.json the result.

```
app.post('/api/infosave', function(req,res){
  async.series([function (cb){
    dbinfo.remove({}, function(err,result){
      if (err) throw err;
      cb(null);
    });
  }, function (cb){

    var bookNum = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < req.body.numBooks; i++) {
      bookNum.push(i+1)
    }
    async.map(bookNum, function(num, cb) {
      dbinfo.create({
        numBooks: num,
        done: false
      }, cb);
    }, cb);

  }, function (cb){
    dbinfo.find({},function(err,result){
      if (err)
        res.send(err);
      res.json(result);
      console.log(result);
      cb(null);
    });
  }], function(error, results) {

  });
});
```

Comment: As far as I understand @floribon, he wants to send the result of the `dbinfo.find()` in the response, in `json` format. But the `res.json(result)` is being called in one of the `series` functions, not in the `series` callback. What must be done is to pass the result of `dbinfo.find()` to the local callback `cb(null, result)` and call the `res.json()` in the `series` callback, with the desired value.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros I don't really mind what he wants, I was amused by his formulation. I guess you should copy that comment into an answer to help everyone out.

Comment: Thank Rodrigo. grateful if you could give a sample code to explain it to a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment: you're calling `res.json()` inside one of the series function, and that won't work. What you should do is pass the result of `dbinfo.find()` to the local callback:

```
dbinfo.find({},function(err,result){
  if (err)
    cb(err);
  cb(null, result);
});
```

, and in the `async.series` callback, call `res.json()`:

```
...
}], function(error, results) {
  if (error) return res.json({ error: error });
  return res.json(results[2]); // the result you want should be third element of results
});
```